# Will React Component not be called when display:none on parent element in nextjs app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am building a teams tab where the build in loading indicator i used.

This means that its basically doing something like

```
<div id="IframeHost">
<iframe src="... my react app" />
</div>
```

where IframeHost has `display:none` until my app calls

```
       const microsoftTeams= await import("@microsoft/teams-js");
       microsoftTeams.initialize()
       microsoftTeams.appInitialization.notifySuccess()
```

however, I am challenged to where I will call `notifySuccess` in my nextjs app, as I am experience that the components javascript is not called client-side.

Is this expected? is there a way to trigger client side components even though the parent element has `display:none`

I made this component to test things out and `ConfigurationTab Load` is logged since the javascript file ofcause loads, but none of the component methods is triggered client side before i manually goes to developer tab and remove the `display:none`.

```
export default class ConfigurationTab extends React.Component<{}, { }> {

    static log(name:string){
        console.log(name);
        if(typeof window === "object")
        {
            console.log(name + " with window");
        }
      
    }
    constructor(props:{}){
        super(props);
        ConfigurationTab.log("ConfigurationTab");
        this.state = {};
    }
    componentDidMount(){
        ConfigurationTab.log("componentDidMount");
    }
    componentDidUpdate(){
        ConfigurationTab.log("componentDidUpdate");
    }
    componentWillUnmount(){
        ConfigurationTab.log("componentWillUnmount");
    }
    static getDerivedStateFromProps(props:{},state:{}){
        ConfigurationTab.log("getDerivedStateFromProps");
            return null;
    }
    static Layout = LayoutWithoutTopBar;
    render(){
        return (
             <div>Loaded</div>
        )
    }
}

ConfigurationTab.log("ConfigurationTab Load");
```